# does MySQL still query through each and every record even if the WHERE condition is set?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website which is highly likely to have thousands of user records.

My interest is to find out if MySQL still would query through each and every record even if the WHERE condition is set or just JUMP straight to the CONDITION record.

for example,.. i have 1000 users and i want to get the details of a user with an id number of 900.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 900;
```

Now, will MySQL still query through all 899 records just to find the user i am looking for or just JUMP straight to that user id... and is this the same case with an auto-incremented id and with a random one?

Comment: If you do not have any indexes then yes. MySQL needs to go through each row to find ones that match. However you should always have some indexes at least primary index on your ID field.

Comment: Generally databases don’t store data in order based of some column unless you expressly tell them to, and they support it. Indexes are there to help with finding data so the answer isn’t a simple one. But in general: no, they will use indexes and in best case only read one row. But they will most likely read multiple parts of the index. And the row data may even be in the index itself without accessing row data.

Comment: Use the `EXPLAIN` command to see how MySQL will execute your query. It will tell you if it's using an index or scanning the entire table.

Comment: thanks a lot guys!! the auto-increment column is the primary key so its indexed.